# Reading and writing line by line in a bash script

Tags: bash, perl

After searching online I was able to figure out how to read a file line by line:

```
while read p; do
  echo $p
done < file.txt
```

But I would actually like to modify the line in the file.
For example:

```
while read p; do
  if condition
  then
    echo $p | perl -i -pe 's/a/b/'
  fi
done < file.txt
```

However this doesn't actually modify the file.

Comment: all text processing tools can read the file line by line and process, there is no need to involve bash loops for this.

Comment: Agree with @karakfa : Do you know that `sed -i 's/a/b/' file` can process the whole file all at once, is much more efficient, and (obviously) has a lot less code? Good luck.

Comment: If you want to edit the file, why don't you use an editor? `ex` and `ed` come to mind…

Comment: What is the condition, exactly?

Comment: re: reading line-by-line, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for best practices. But... if you're doing that, why in the world would you also use `perl -i` or `sed -i`? If you want to replace one string with another, then `echo "${p//a/b}"` will do so **much** more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**   A *far* better version of bash code added.  Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for comments.

---

Your Perl one-liner takes a line piped into it by `echo $p |`, getting its standard input that way. It doesn't do anything with the file itself, so the `-i` flag has no effect. The `-p` makes it print to the standard output stream. So that whole line, `echo ...`, doesn't touch the file.

You can redirect the output to a new file and then move that to overwrite `file.txt`. Here is a simple minded example, that appends each line to a new file. For better bash code see the update below.

```
while read p; do
    if condition
    then
        echo $p | perl -pe 's/a/b/' >> temp_out.txt
    else
        echo $p >> temp_out.txt
    fi
done < file.txt
mv temp_out.txt file.txt
```

We have to add the `else` where all unmodified lines are also appended.  Note that in general we cannot have just some lines replaced but the whole file has to be re-written.

If this is all that the script does you can do it with a very simple one-liner, see the end.  If more work is done you can also put it all in a Perl script but I take it that there may be other good reasons for a bash script.

---

**Update**   A much better version of the above.  See `read` and `echo` in [Builtins in Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins)

- Appending each line opens the file anew each time without a need for that.
  Just redirect at the end of the loop, much like it is done in the terminal
- `read` uses backslash for escaping, removing it from input. Turn that off with `-r`
- Trailing white space is removed, as a part of breaking the line into words. Suppress this by unsetting the variable that controls which characters are used for splitting, `IFS=`
- The `echo $p` can do all kinds of unintended things.  A formatted print is better, `printf '%s\n' "$p"`, or at least `echo "$p"`

With this,

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
    if condition
    then
        echo "$p" | perl -pe 's/a/b/'
    else
        echo "$p"
    fi
done < file.txt  > temp_out.txt
mv temp_out.txt file.txt
```

Finally, if the sole purpose of the Perl one-liner were to run a simple substitution, it is much better to simply do that in the shell itself than to have a pipeline and run a whole new process for each line.

```
echo "${p//a/b}"
```

Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for raising all these points in comments.

---

*A few comments on Perl one-liners.  See documentation at [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).*

The command `perl -e '...'` executes any valid Perl code between `''`. When we add the `-n` or `-p` switch it also reads standard input and executes that code on a line of it at the time, where `-p` also prints out each line after it's processed. The standard input can be supplied to it from a file,

```
perl -pe '...' input.txt
```

in which case adding `-i` flag will result in the file being changed in-place.  Or, the input can be piped into it, for example

```
echo "input text" | perl -pe '...'
```

in which case the processed line is printed to standard output. This can be redirected to a file, as in the answer above.

---

To make changes to a given file a line at a time you only need this on the command line

```
perl -i -pe 's/a/b/' file.txt
```

If there is more work to do then it may well be better to put it in a script, of course. In this case the one-liner can be a command in the bash script as well, replacing all that code above (unless some bash-specific functionality is preferred for processing lines).

Comment: Putting `>> temp_out.txt` on each `echo` is horribly inefficient -- it's reopening the output file every time you want to write to it, instead of just holding one file descriptor open for write for the entire operationt.

Comment: Put `> temp_out.txt` after the `done` on your loop, and you'll avoid all those `open` and `close` operations.

Comment: Also, `echo $p` is buggy. Use `printf '%s\n' "$p"`, or at least `echo "$p"` -- though the latter still will do things like delete a line containing only `-n`, it won't have the bad side effects of `echo $p`, which will replace a line containing `*` with a list of files in the current directory, replace tabs with spaces, etc.

Comment: Also, change your `read` to `read -r`, or your loop will remove backslashes from the input.

Comment: Also, make it `while IFS= read -r p` -- without the `IFS=`, you'll delete trailing whitespace from the input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I had that in mind originally (and then messed it up) -- but then I wanted a clear answer.  However, you are right of course. I'm inclined to leave what's there and _add_ this explanation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Well, sure, thank you. I didn't mean to touch OP code, just to fix the direct error.  You are right, thank you, I'll add all this.

Comment: (One might also consider using `"${p//a/b}"` to do the replacement in shell, rather than requiring a pipeline and subprocess for every line).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Thank you very much -- I didn't mean to go to all this but you are completely right, I should.  Also, thanks for some pointers here which I didn't know about.